# Item wrong length when use pandas isin to filter column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm experienced item wrong length when use pandas isin to filter column

Here's my code

`selected_raw_data = raw_data[raw_data.columns.isin(selected['Column'])].copy()`

Error message here

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-f7f86ab9946e> in <module>
----> 1 selected_raw_data = raw_data[raw_data.columns.isin(selected['Column'])].copy()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2891         # Do we have a (boolean) 1d indexer?
   2892         if com.is_bool_indexer(key):
-> 2893             return self._getitem_bool_array(key)
   2894 
   2895         # We are left with two options: a single key, and a collection of keys,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _getitem_bool_array(self, key)
   2937             )
   2938         elif len(key) != len(self.index):
-> 2939             raise ValueError(
   2940                 f"Item wrong length {len(key)} instead of {len(self.index)}."
   2941             )

ValueError: Item wrong length 396 instead of 362.
```

Comment: @AnuragDabas Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).

Comment: `raw_data[selected['Column']].copy()` ?

Comment: `selected` is a dict of list of column names ?

Comment: @SeaBean I'l give you green checkmark if you write in answer

Comment: Selected is a dataframe, you got it right @SeaBean

Comment: Right, Pandas often accepts list-like or series just like the way we do with a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming selected['Column'] resolves to a list or list-like (like a series or a column of a dataframe) of column names, you can use:

```
raw_data[selected['Column']].copy()
```

to filter for the selected columns.